# How to gain weight for one year infant

Tags: infant, bottle-feeding, formula, babyfood

Are there any natural home made equivalent recipes for baby formula milk . Is it possible to make natural formula milk at home itself containing all nutrients found in breast milk?

Also  what other natural foodstuff can for a 1 year(9 month) old with the goal to gain weight?

Note: Already we are giving breast milk and her mother is again 7 month pregnant and we forsee that breast milk would stop due to nearing the labour but that is not helping to gain weight as per the Indian standards and the pediatrician **did not recommend lactogen** or any supplementation except Vit D and calcium but was worried about weight gain for which she asked to take natural food stuffs like mashed potatoes , egg yolk,etc  but this is not helping to gain the weight due to fussiness and **we dont want to fall upon lactogen or any commercial feed**.

Comment: You need to make this more general.  The focus on 'lactogen' is probably a mistake.  If you're asking "What do I feed my 1yo to help her gain weight", ask that, and add in the comments about being fussy about eating solid foods.

Comment: This question is also asking for us to replace the advice of a Dr and fill the role of a nutritionist.  Good Doctors, in my experience, try healthy solutions first and only progress to stronger, perhaps medicinal solutions later.  Update your doctor and seeking renewed advice.

Comment: @Joe I changed the question as suggested , thanks

Comment: Can you clarify the child's age - is she 1 yr, 9 months, or 1yr and 9 months? How much does the child weigh? Has she lost weight?

Answer (score 2):

Here's the problem. Your doctor has recommended a particular solution. Anything we recommend would be a second opinion *against their recommendation*, and taking our advice over a doctor's would be... not good.

The best thing to do is to **overcome the fussiness**. Either mix something you know your child likes into the mash, or instead of egg-yolks, make an omlette. Experiment with other high-carb/fat foods.

Eat with them so that they feel like an adult by eating.

Also, at one year, you're able to switch to full-fat cow's milk, so I'd start with that and proper food, and watch for any signs of nutritional deficiencies.